# How do I select checked input in a div to display in an another div ? (without javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, css-selectors

I have a project where I have to make a menu.

When I click on an `<input />`, it has to display a `<div>`.

It works when I write the list directly in the code, but the problem is when I put the list into a `<div>`, it doesn't work. Why?

Here the code that works:

```css
#home,
#vin,
#ipp,
#rez {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#acceuilCheck,
#vinlandCheck,
#ippoCheck,
#rezeroCheck,
#acceuil,
#vinland,
#ippo,
#rezero {
    display: none;
}
#acceuilCheck:checked~.paragraphe #acceuil {
    display: block;
}
#vinlandCheck:checked~.paragraphe #vinland {
    display: block;
}
#ippoCheck:checked~.paragraphe #ippo {
    display: block;
}
#rezeroCheck:checked~.paragraphe #rezero {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>Wiki No Anime</title>

</head>
<body>
        <input id="acceuilCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="acceuilCheck" id="home">Accueil</label>
        <input id="vinlandCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="vinlandCheck" id="vin">Vinland</label>
        <input id="ippoCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="ippoCheck" id="ipp">Ippo</label>
        <input id="rezeroCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="rezeroCheck" id="rez">Re:Zero</label>
    <div class="paragraphe">
        <div id="acceuil">Presentation anime</div>
        <div id="vinland">Viland c'est du ma nibru ça</div>
        <div id="ippo">Ippo franchement c'est trop magnifique</div>
        <div id="rezero">Re:Zero est un anime de ouffff !!!!</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here the code that doesn't work:

```css
#home,
#vin,
#ipp,
#rez {
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#acceuilCheck,
#vinlandCheck,
#ippoCheck,
#rezeroCheck,
#acceuil,
#vinland,
#ippo,
#rezero {
    display: none;
}
.menu #acceuilCheck:checked~.paragraphe #acceuil {
    display: block;
}
.menu #vinlandCheck:checked~.paragraphe #vinland {
    display: block;
}
.menu #ippoCheck:checked~.paragraphe #ippo {
    display: block;
}
.menu #rezeroCheck:checked~.paragraphe #rezero {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <title>Wiki No Anime</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        <input id="acceuilCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="acceuilCheck" id="home">Accueil</label>
        <input id="vinlandCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="vinlandCheck" id="vin">Vinland</label>
        <input id="ippoCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="ippoCheck" id="ipp">Ippo</label>
        <input id="rezeroCheck" name="list" type="radio">
        <label for="rezeroCheck" id="rez">Re:Zero</label>
    </div>
    <div class="paragraphe">
        <div id="acceuil">Presentation anime</div>
        <div id="vinland">Viland c'est du ma nibru ça</div>
        <div id="ippo">Ippo franchement c'est trop magnifique</div>
        <div id="rezero">Re:Zero est un anime de ouffff !!!!</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do this without JavaScript?

Comment: It's because "~" is used to select general siblings elements which share the same parent, in you case you are trying to select .paragraph #acceuil while being inside the .menu div so it can't work because .paragraph is not inside the .menu div. Maybe you should create a HTML file for each possible paragraph navigate to them with href when you click on a menu item.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, what can I do to replace the "~" ?

Comment: Check my edited answer

Comment: Writing a whole website in a single HTML isn't a good idea that's why you should separate each page and be able to navigate to them thanks to your menu

Comment: You mean with an "a href" ?

Comment: In your menu just create <a></a> element for each different paragraph, move your paragraphs to new HTML files for each paragraph and then you would be able to access them by clicking on the <a></a> element by setting a navigation link with href : <a href="/acceuil">Acceuil</a> for example, Anyway i suggest you to check a basic HTML navigation tutorial

Comment: Yup I think that's the best but the client wants to display contents only in one page... Sorry for wasting your time :/